# Jquery loop animation and freeze on hover

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

I have a fiddle set up, but I need to expand it, I have tried and failed all night, so I have stripped out all my attempts and just left the main parts. Please see this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/nqQG9/

I would like to know how to "loop" the whole animation for infinity, but most important is to be able to pause the animation on mouse enter or hover for any one of the divs, then either on mouseout continue animation or clicking the link will link off the page.

**also If this is possible (not sure) I would love to randomise the timings that the divs appear, but always visible for say 1/2 a second??
]
Fiddle code below..

```
 $('#one').delay(2000).fadeIn(200);
 $('#one').delay(500).fadeOut(200);

 $('#two').delay(3000).fadeIn(200);
 $('#two').delay(500).fadeOut(200);

 $('#three').delay(4000).fadeIn(200);
 $('#three').delay(500).fadeOut(200);

 $('#four').delay(5000).fadeIn(200);
 $('#four').delay(500).fadeOut(200);

 $('#five').delay(6000).fadeIn(200);
 $('#five').delay(500).fadeOut(200);

 $('#six').delay(7000).fadeIn(200);
 $('#six').delay(500).fadeOut(200);
```

Comment: updated to include the loop, just need to know how to pause the animation on hovering on any of the divs...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/nqQG9/1/

Answer (score 0):

following code fades elements randomly and pauses the fade effect on mouse over. **it requires you to add "box" class to all elements.**

```
    $(function () {
        function fadeAll() {
           var id = 1 + parseInt(Math.random() * 5) % 5;
           $('.box:nth-child('+id+')').stop().delay(500+parseInt(Math.random() * 500)).fadeIn('fast', function () {
              $(this).stop().delay(500 +parseInt(Math.random() * 500)).fadeOut('fast');
           })
           window.timeout = window.setTimeout(fadeAll, 500);
        }

        $('.box').hover(function(){
           $(this).css('opacity', 1);
           window.clearTimeout(window.timeout);
           $('.box').stop();
        },function(){
           $('.box').fadeOut('fast');
           window.timeout = window.setTimeout(fadeAll, 500);
        });

        fadeAll();
     })
```